# Alfresco Repo Side working on Document Upload

Tags: alfresco, conceptual, concept, alfresco-enterprise

I would like to understand how does the Alfresco Repo works whenever any document is uploaded. How exactly the content is stored in file system metadata in DB and indexes in Solr respectively ?

Comment: It's generally best to treat Alfresco as a magical "black box" for storing and retrieving your content. Accessing the DB directly is very much "super-expert" level! What are you trying to do? Tell us that, and we might be able to help....

Comment: I am generally trying to get into "Black Box" and explore what exactly happens. I have being working on Alfresco from last 2 to 3 years but I didn't come across the question which I asked on any forum or community page. I am just a curious soul trying to figure out what and how things exactly happens behind the scene.

Comment: Alfresco is open source, so you could just go read the code to see how it works! Otherwise the Alfresco Community Forum is likely to be a better place for a discussion, Stack Overflow is more for single Q&A

Comment: Thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 2):

You have to dive deep down in Alfresco documentation and code as well for getting all these clarifications.

Alfresco stores the documents in the physical directories in proper folder structures(which you can define in your code as well). CMIS services expose the functionalities for all operations which you can perform on documents. CMIS internally uses cache in CMIS session for better performance.

Documents metadata and node references all are being stored in DB(PostgreSQL) and indexing of documents are being done automatically through Solr in latest versions.

You have to specify the fields which you want in Solr document for indexing. Searching documents in Solr is faster than DB but queryConsistency is Eventual for Solr. So, as per your use case you have to decide whether query Solr or DB.

So, whenever any operation(CRUD) on any document is being done, it reflects in DB first then async indexing of that document happens in Solr. This Async indexing leads to Eventual consistency.